# Dockerfile with multiple base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I m trying to create a simple dockerfile in which I need to build my nodejs project in multiple steps :

- Installing and caching my dependencies
- Running my unit tests
- Running my acceptance tests
- Building my project

to ensure that my project is working great. Here's what I m having for now :

```
FROM node:6.9

# Enviroment variables
ENV HOMEDIR /data

RUN mkdir -p ${HOMEDIR}
WORKDIR ${HOMEDIR}

# install all dependencies
ADD package.json ./
RUN npm install

# ... some stuff goes here without any importance
# add node content initially
ADD . .
CMD CI=true npm test && npm run test:acceptance && npm run build
```

When running my acceptance tests, I use a selenium server. **And I need java for this**.

The fact is that I don't have java installed, and I wanted to use a "standard" image, **while conserving my current node:6.9 image**, that would allow me to switch easily from version to version (like https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/). I mean there that I don't want to manually install JAVA on my current image.

My problem is that I can't use multiple FROM sources inside my dockerfile and I don't know if what I need is even possible.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Sounds like you should run the acceptance tests in a separate docker image.  Maybe [Docker Selenium](https://medium.com/@garrensmith/consistent-selenium-testing-with-docker-f2d5a24a1bc5) can help you?

Comment: Maybe should I split my needs into another one. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Note, that you can run the Selenium server on another host. All-in-all, it's a server. So you can run your tests inside your Node container, but only host the Selenium server on another container with Java.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a great idea ! This way I run all my tests in the same container, but using a "remote" selenium server. I m going to try this. Thanks for the comments :D

Comment: @Skahrz You can do that, but be aware that if you run the tests in your application image, any stray files created by the tests will be "baked in" to the image.  See e.g. [this blog post](http://blog.terranillius.com/post/docker_testing/) for some discussion of different strategies.

Answer (score 1):

The docker way is have small and lightweight image as possible. You *production* image does not need a java, selenium and etc...

Building and testing application must be outside of container. It can be another image (with selenium, java, etc; or building cluster with multiple containers like selenium, java, etc) for building production images.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to have a base image that only contains the base OS and required software that your application require for running.

Use that base image and create multiple images for different tests.
Once you are done with all the testing use the same base image to package and dockerize your application.